# Proving sequence is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A=\{x \in \mathbb{Q} : x^2 < 2\}$. Let $x_j \in A$ for $j=1,2,3,\ldots$ be an increasing sequence such that there are corresponding $y_j$ for $j=1,2,3,\ldots$ satisfying

$y_j^2 > 2$ and $y_j - x_j < (\frac{1}{2})^j$

How do I prove that $x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots$ is Cauchy?

Answer (score 2):

**hint**

Use

$$x_j<x_{j+1}<\sqrt{2}<y_j$$

$$x_{j+1} - x_j <y_j-x_j <\frac{1}{2^j}$$

And for $n,p\ge 1,$

$$x_{n+p}-x_n<\sum_{j=n}^{n+p-1}\frac{1}{2^j}=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}(1-\frac{1}{2^p})$$

$$<\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$$

So, given an $ \epsilon>0$, because of $$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}=0$$

there exists $ N \in \Bbb N $ such that

$$(\forall p\ge 1) \;\;(\forall n\ge N) \;\;$$
$$|x_{n+p}-x_n|<\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}<\epsilon$$
Done.

Answer (score 0):

$x_j$ is increasing and $x_j^{2} <2 <4$. This implies that $|x_j| <2$. Any increasing bounded sequence is convergent, hence Cauchy.

Comment: Why would a comment be written in the answer box? It is not expected for a 184k user.